# how to make an led turn on when something gets close to an ultrasonic sensor

Tags: arduino-uno

Hey I just started using arduino and so far can't get any help with how to write a code for an led to turn on when someone gets in range of a three pin ultrasonic sensor, and off when they are out of a specific range.

Any help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried lighting an LED? Have you tried getting the distance from the ultrasonic sensor?

Comment: i have already done all of that

Comment: Then you just need to do some comparisons.  Learn about the "if" command.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this and check that at least you can reproduce the desired effect:
http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Ping?from=Tutorial.UltrasoundSensor

Then you can refer to this for the part related to driving the LED:
http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink?from=Tutorial.BlinkingLED

Since the ultra sound demo already calculates the distance, you can do the test on that to decide when to turn ON/OFF the LED.